# Upload entire folder if extis by post to server Using java

Tags: java, android

I am a newbie in java and I need to complete this app and send an entire folder by Post to my server.

Now the code works but I need to check if a specific folder name and path exists and then send all files with the thread upload function.

The referenced code:

```
public class UploadToServer extends Activity {

    TextView messageText;
    Button uploadButton;
    int serverResponseCode = 0;
    ProgressDialog dialog = null;

    String upLoadServerUri = null;

    /**********  File Path *************/
    final String uploadFilePath = "/mnt/sdcard/folder/";
    final String uploadFileName = "sample.jpg";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload_to_server);

        uploadButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.uploadButton);
        messageText  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.messageText);

        messageText.setText("Uploading file path :- " + uploadFilePath + uploadFileName);

        /************* Php script path ****************/
        upLoadServerUri = "http://www.tutomax.com/uploads/Receiver.php";

        uploadButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {            
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                dialog = ProgressDialog.show(UploadToServer.this, "", "Uploading file...", true);

                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                             runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                    public void run() {
                                        messageText.setText("uploading started.....");
                                    }
                                });                      

                             uploadFile(uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);

                        }
                      }).start();        
                }
            });
    }

    public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {
```

.... REST CODE UPLOAD FUNCTION

Comment: What part of the code you have posted is relevant to your question? Please thin down the code; no one wants to read through all of that.

Comment: Hi Gunr2171, Done sorry, you are right it's very long one. Thanks for your advice. Cya

Answer (score 0):

how about travel all files under the specified folder, then upload files matched one by one.